# Codeblocks: How Could I Turn the Left Part Black?

Tags: codeblocks

[image]

No Options In Editor are to be found

Comment: Please post code samples as text, rather than as images.

Comment: Sry. But the Q is sort of associated with IDE, not the code itself. I don't know what to do with it.